# Insert array data into template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constants

I want to fill a template with some integers from an array but this doesn't seem to be allowed in C++. An example:

I define a constant array with Integers.

```
const int array[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

My template works like that:

```
template<int T> TestClass ...
```

In the following, the first way is no problem, but the second way does not compile:

```
TestClass<12> ...          // works
TestClass<array[0]> ...    // does not work
```

The compiler says that the operator '[' is not allowed in a temlate. But what is the reason for that and how can I solve this situation elegantly? Is it also possible to use a counter `i`of a `for`-loop to choose the Integer of the array, like:

```
TestClass<array[i]>
```

Comment: No templates in [tag:c] so don't tag the question as [tag:c].

Comment: Sorry, too fast! You are right.

Comment: Try again, using `constexpr` array and proper syntax (not parentheses to instantiate the template).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your array to a `constexpr` variable:

```
constexpr int array[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

or even better:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 4> myArray{0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Since your array will be `constexpr`, it's usage will be valid at compile-time.

Be sure to enable c++14 for the `std::array` version.

Comment: Thats very interesting. The editor still marks an error but it compiles (Why?) When I now try to declare the templates in a **for-loop with the counter i** it does not compile: `TestClass<array[i]>` Is there a trick as well?

Comment: Your variable `i` must be a `constexpr` too. Since you cannot have `constexpr` function parameter, you must have `i` as a template parameter.

Comment: But I cannot increment the _constant counter-variable_ `i` in a for-loop...?

Answer (score 0):

An integral type template parameter such as int in your class **template TestClass ...** should be a compile time constant, that's why such code wouldn't compile.

Comment: But the array is declared constant. Is not compile time constant? How can I use some nice-arranged integer (from an array) in a template?

Comment: To make it compile time constant you should declare it as **constexpr**